# Number of channels in System.Drawing.Bitmap C#

Tags: c#, image, channel

I'm coding in C#, and loading images this way :

```
// loading image
string imageFileName = "myImage.jpg";
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFileName, false);

// trying to display color so that I know how many channels I have
// except it always displays 4 values, whether I have 1, 3 or 4 channels
Color color = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(color.ToString());

// locking the bitmap's bits
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

// doing stuff that requires me to know the number of channels of the image, amongst other things

// unlocking the bitmap's bits
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

I need to know the number of channels in my image (usually they are grayscale (1), RGB (3) or RGBA (4)), and I don't know how is that information storred.

**EDIT :**
I'm not looking to force a pixel format. I'm trying to load an image, and figure out procedurally what is the number of channel in the image I loaded.

Comment: The simplest and usually fastest way to do this is to simply force the pixel format so your code works regardless of the actual number of channels.  There is only one pixel format that is best, it is 32bppArgb.  Which lets you use an int* to address the pixels, fastest way to read and write.  As a counterpoint, the 24bppRgb you'd get from a JPEG image is quite awkward, you have to use a byte* and that costs 3 read/writes for every pixel.  That is slow.  The conversion however, if one is required, is not for free.  You have to measure.

Comment: I'm not sure it answer my question. I'm not looking to force a pixel format. I'm merely trying to load an image, and figure out procedurally what is the number of channel in the image I loaded.

Comment: I know what you asked, my explicit recommendation is to not have to ask.

Comment: Yes, I finally understood what both you and TaW were saying (that's why I deleted the comment). C# is not my main language, so I had difficulty figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation:

You need to use an [overload of the Bitmap contructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) that takes a PixelFormat parameter.

Usage:

The the [bitmap.PixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.pixelformat?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_PixelFormat) property will tell you what you have.

[Here is more info about the PixelFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Though I don't need to use an overload of the Bitmap constructor (especially since none of them takes a file name AND a pixel format), and I need to know the number of channels for an image I load from disk, the Bitmap.PixelFormat property is indeed what I was looking for. I overlooked it when I was looking on my own before asking the question because I was expecting something like Bitmap.ChannelCount or whatever. Thank you for you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `PixelFormat` property, you can read about in on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

You can combine with: [GetPixelFormatSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getpixelformatsize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_GetPixelFormatSize_System_Drawing_Imaging_PixelFormat_) it to get the bytes per pixel if you want.

Comment: Yep, with that I only have to add `System.Drawing.Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat)` in my code.